# OS X Server MailBox size expand

Tags: macos, email, osx-server

I'm running OS X Server app version 5.1. I have mail configured for all my users. I have a default value of 200 MB for each mail box, as the server is only 256 GB. Is there any way to change the mail box location to my attached external NAS so I can locate more then 50 GB mail space to each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You two options to change the mail box location:

1. You can either change the Server Data location to an external volume or a share:

   Open Server.app. In the left pane choose Server -> *server_name* -> Settings -> Service Data. Hit the button *Change Location* and choose another volume. This will copy **all** service data to a new location. Before migrating the services will be shut down automatically.
2. Or you copy the Mail folder /Library/Server/Mail to a different location

   Stop the mail service. Copy/rsync the folder /Library/Server/Mail to a different volume/share. Keep the original permissions! Remove the original folder and symlink back the new location to /Library/Server/*Mail*.

After moving the mail data location adjust the mail box size and start the mail service again.